# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166) Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I try to fetch data from flutter firebase by using HTTP URL but this error occured.
pls, help me to solve this error.
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
Products.fetchAndSetProducts
thank you

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
  final filterString = filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"' :'';
  var url = 'https://cowmilknew.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (extractedData == null) {
      return;
    }
     url =
    'https://cowmilknew.firebaseio.com/RetailerWishlist/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
    final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
    final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);

    final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
    extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
      loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: prodId,
        title: prodData['title'],
        description: prodData['description'],
        price: prodData['price'],
        isFavorite: favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
        imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
      ));
    });
    _items = loadedProducts;
    notifyListeners();
  } catch (error) {
    throw (error);
  }
}
```

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<Products>(context,listen: false).fetchAndSetProducts().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error

Comment: Check variable type of id and price one of them is not matching with json data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly where is your error because you didn't provide the complete error log, but its clearly you are trying to pass an int to a string so I'm guessing maybe the error is in price: prodData['price']
so do this convert the price to an int

```
price: prodData['price'].toString();
```

Comment: before I write  ` double price;` but now changed to ` int price;` now this error show: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'.

Comment: when  i try ur method,error : string cannot assign to int. How I solve this issue??